# Generalizing Jensen's inequality to several variables.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

> Let $f\colon D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, where
>   $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex open set. Find a sufficient
>   condition on the derivative of $f$ such that for any $x_i\in D$,
>   $1\leq i\leq n$, we have $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)}{n}\geq f\bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}\bigg).$$

I thought up this question myself. I was wondering whether there is a simple test (for example, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\geq0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\geq0$) so that I can use the inequality above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can prove generalized Jensen inequality by induction. For example, you can find it [***here***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_1_.28finite_form.29).

Thus it is sufficient to ensure that the function $\,f:D\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\,$ is *convex*.
I am not sure whether it is possible to come up with condition on the $1^\mathrm{st}$ derivatives of $\,f$  such that it will guarantee convexity of the function. However, there is a [***well known result***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties) involving $2^\mathrm{nd}$ derivatives which should do the trick:

> $\ldots$ a continuous, twice differentiable function of several variables is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in another answer, the condition you want is convexity. As for a necessary and sufficient condition using first derivatives: A differentiable function $f$ is convex if and only if its gradient is monotone, i. e. for all $x, y$ it holds that

$$
\langle \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y), x-y\rangle \geq 0.
$$